# Is there a framework in Java to setup up persistence layer?

Tags: java, unit-testing, persistence, dao

I try to write unit tests for the persistence layer of a Java web application. I use JUnit for testing the service layer and I want to use it for the persistence layer, too.

Because the application is highly customizable, the persistence layer can be changed by configuration to use JDBC-enabled databases (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle) and embedded databases (sqljet). Is there a framework, that helps me to define a data set used for testing and setting up the data storage with it? My goal is, to write one set of tests and use it for all implementations of the persistence layer. DbUnit is not an option, because I have non-JDBC versions of the persistence layer (sqljet).

Thanks in advance,

Markus

Answer (score 3):

DBUnit might help you

> DbUnit is a JUnit extension (also usable with Ant) targeted at
>   database-driven projects that, among other things, puts your database
>   into a known state between test runs. This is an excellent way to
>   avoid the myriad of problems that can occur when one test case
>   corrupts the database and causes subsequent tests to fail or
>   exacerbate the damage.
>
> DbUnit has the ability to export and import your database data to and
>   from XML datasets. Since version 2.0, DbUnit can also work with very
>   large datasets when used in streaming mode. DbUnit can also help you
>   to verify that your database data match an expected set of values.

http://www.dbunit.org/

Comment: I found this framework, too. But I think, it's JDBC-related. I found methods using or returing java.sql.Connection. For embedded databases like sqljet, I have no JDBC connection...

Comment: You always have a connection when using a database. When you use SQLJet you are using a low-level API to connect to SQLLite, and the database is not SQLJet but SQLLite. If you look for a JDBC connector for SQLLite I am sure you can find one